# Drupal excessive menu parts

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, hook-menu

In a module development (webtv) I am providing a generic block that can be configured for its contents (playlists). On the configure form there is a list of added contents (playlists) along with links "add new playlist" and "edit" existing one placed next to each entry. As the block configuration path is: "admin/build/block/configure/[my_module_name]/[block_delta]".

And I am expecting to add/edit playlist form on a separate page and should be accessible on:
admin/build/block/configure/[my_module_name]/[block_delta]/playlist/add
and 
admin/build/block/configure/[my_module_name]/[block_delta]/playlist/[playlist_id]/edit

For this I added two entries in hook_menu with page callback as drupal_get_form and page argument as form defining function.

After clearing cache and running cron, links does not server playlist add/edit page but redirects to block configure page.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to extend block configure page into sub pages?

Comment: Adding in your hook_menu code would make it easier to diagnose the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum allowed menu parts in a drupal(6) URL are limited to 7. In my problem I have quoted paths with 8 and 9 parts that was the issue.

```
 admin/build/block/configure/[my_module_name]/[block_delta]/playlist/add
 admin/build/block/configure/[my_module_name]/[block_delta]/playlist/[playlist_id]/edit
```

In Drupal 7 the limit is expanded to 9.

It can manually be changed in the file `drupal/includes/menu.inc` as `define('MENU_MAX_PARTS', 12);`

Comment: Hacking core is the 8th deadly sin in Drupal, so I would highly advise against it.