# path not registering via hook_menu_alter in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, menu, hook, alter

I am adding a new path by hook_menu_alter but when I access this path, proper page callback is not triggered. when I inspected what router_item is picked by menu_execute_active_handler function in drupal core , it prints a parent path which lacks last 1 path argument.
This is how I have menu_alter.

```
function mainlist_slot_menu_alter(&$items) {
   $items['user/%user/categories/bird/list/%/%ctools_js/%']  = array(
     'title'    => 'Mainlist slot fulfiller',
     'page callback'  => 'mainlist_slot',
     'page arguments' => array(1, 5, 6,7),
     'access callback'=> 'mainlist_slot_access',
     'access arguments' => array(1,5,7)
  );
}
```

Other module have also implemented hook_menu_alter

```
function mainlist_menu_alter(&$items){
 $items['user/%user/categories/bird/list/%mainlist'] = array(
  'title callback' => 'mainlist_title',
  'title arguments'=> array(5),
  'description'    => 'Page showing mainlist for referenced user',
  'page callback' =>'mainlist_view',
  'page arguments' => array(5),
  'load arguments' => array(1),
  'access callback' => 'mainlist_access',
  'access arguments' => array(1,5),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
 )
);
```

So now when I access path `user/1/categories/bird/list/1/nojs/91`
It should trigger page callback defined in first snippet but instead it invokes page callback from second snippet. So I assumed that hook_alter implementation in first snippet might not be called at all but when I  put some debugging statements in this hook for $items array , it prints them well, so this function is called properly but only path in this alter is not getting registered.

Please let me know what can be reason for this behavior.    Thanks in advance

Comment: I have found that certain code in include/menu.inc is trimming down path and so proper page callback is not triggered. I found    `define('MENU_MAX_PARTS', 7);`   in include/menu.inc 

SO my question becomes how I can modify this limit and why menu parts are capped like this. any pitfalls for circumventing this ?

Comment: What does the second _1_ represent in `user/1/categories/bird/list/1/nojs/91`?

Comment: @jerdiggity on my website list is kind of content type and the "1" following it is list identifier

Comment: You may be able to increase it:
* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343259/drupal-excessive-menu-parts

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to truncate your path with one or two parts! Or you can re-define `MENU_MAX_PARTS`. But for that, you will need to modify the core and I'm sure you do not want to do that, right?